# Is it possible to have a subset of variables in a ggplot2 legend with facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot with three groups. I have used facets to get the graph as I want, and I managed to unite the colour and shape into a single legend (as shown below). The problem, however, is that the legend contains all the six variable names, whereas having only two suffice.

Here is my current output:
[image]

Is it possible to obtain a legend with only two keys: "Divergence" and "% of Women" (instead of the current 6 keys) ?

Here is the code used to produce the plot:

```
years <- c('97','98','99','00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11')
years <- factor(years, levels=years, ordered=T)             
phy_ratio <- c(0.124516129032258, 0.11545988258317,  0.115190784737221, 0.120919881305638, 0.132198952879581, 0.147636363636364, 0.171033478893741, 0.155994550408719, 0.150121065375303, 0.182989690721649, 0.19466515323496,  0.194550408719346, 0.203811540497618, 0.214399152991001, 0.195157384987893)
phy_kldiv <- c(0.040955264723678, 0.001463273151143, 0.011790601776013, 0.00575319295143,  0.003434619043043, 0.001405575036774, 0.012395353183334, 0.002864433864471, 0.006622155735437, 0.074859543690491, 0.013087320475828, 0.023585193439178, 0.08866626868359,  0.07879809266254,  0.04536730602564)
mat_ratio <- c(0.236086175942549,  0.253846153846154, 0.256481481481481, 0.246901811248808, 0.273267326732673, 0.290076335877863, 0.265861027190332, 0.283457249070632, 0.27098919368246,  0.296156744536549, 0.289834174477289, 0.309506790564689, 0.311612903225806, 0.293710691823899, 0.286604361370716)
mat_kldiv <- c(0.024935971694693,  0.012778283551598, 0.019350970177576, 0.00988763992456,  0.008284622131022, 0.014700010603506, 0.015235482499119, 0.023914776035294, 0.018878559121565, 0.073688344207842, 0.042784809873074, 0.052110805729914, 0.072367460713338, 0.017494663842138, 0.019605349179071)
psc_ratio <- c(0, 0, 0, 0.370182555780933, 0.325227963525836, 0.416528925619835, 0.379727685325265, 0.333901192504259, 0.396440129449838, 0.357142857142857, 0.412265758091993, 0.415605095541401, 0, 0, 0)
psc_kldiv <- c(0, 0, 0, 0.156958669813655, 0.02319115435268,  0.019560312744745, 0.142939013816555, 0.050687092785045, 0.030903744617805, 0.021234599637716, 0.049901381314152, 0.176930275568253, 0, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame("Years"=years,
                 '% of Women (Physics)'=phy_ratio,
                 'Divergence (Physics)'=phy_kldiv,
                 '% of Women (Maths)'=mat_ratio,
                 'Divergence (Maths)'=mat_kldiv,
                 '% of Women (Polit. Sci.)'=psc_ratio,
                 'Divergence (Polit. Sci.)'=psc_kldiv,
                 check.names=F)
df.m <- melt(df, id="Years")
df.m <- transform(df.m, facet=ifelse(variable %in% c('% of Women (Physics)',
                                                      'Divergence (Physics)'), 'phy',
                                 ifelse(variable %in% c('% of Women (Maths)',
                                                             'Divergence (Maths)'),'mat',
                                        ifelse(variable %in% c('% of Women (Polit. Sci.)', 'Divergence (Polit. Sci.)'), 'psc', 'mat'))))
g <- ggplot(df.m, aes(group=1, x=Years, y=value, colour=variable, shape=variable))
g <- g + scale_colour_manual(name='',
                             labels=c('Phy: % of Women', 'Phy: Divergence',
                                      'Maths: % of Women', 'Maths: Divergence',
                                      'Polit. Sci: % of Women', 'Polit. Sci: Divergence'),
                             values=c('chartreuse4', 'deepskyblue3', 'chartreuse4', 'deepskyblue3', 'chartreuse4', 'deepskyblue3'))
g <- g + scale_shape_manual(name='',
                            labels=c('Phy: % of Women', 'Phy: Divergence',
                                     'Maths: % of Women', 'Maths: Divergence',
                                     'Polit. Sci: % of Women', 'Polit. Sci: Divergence'),
                            values=c(19, 17, 19, 17, 19, 17))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(colour=variable), size=3)
g <- g + facet_grid(.~facet)
g <- g + coord_cartesian(ylim=(c(0.0,0.45)))
g <- g + scale_x_discrete("", expand=c(0.01, 0.01))
g <- g + scale_y_continuous(name="")
g <- g + guides(colour=guide_legend(title='', ncol=2, keywidth=unit(2,'lines')))
g <- g + theme(legend.position=c(0.33,0.72),
               legend.justification=c(0,0),
               legend.key=element_blank(),
               legend.background=element_rect(colour='black', fill='transparent'),
               legend.text=element_text(size=12),
               panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
               panel.margin=unit(1, 'lines'),
               axis.text=element_text(size=12,color="black"),
               axis.title=element_text(size=16),
               strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

Comment: Yes, just map the color and shape to a variable that only contains those two values. Can you post your code?

Comment: Without seeing exactly how you made this, it is hard to help. However, I'm guessing that you have a single column which contains information about department (Phy, Maths, Polit. Sci) and the variable (% of Women, Divergence). You must have split the first part out to be able to facet by it. Now you just need to split the variable part out and use that as the mapping for shape/color. A more specific answer can be given with a reproducible example.

Comment: As per both your comments, I have included the code used to produce this graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up after your definition of `df`

Make libraries used explicit:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("grid")
```

A different way to make `df.m` which also includes pulling out the two different measures ("% of Women" and "Divergence") into one column and the department ("Maths", "Physics", "Polit. Sci.") into another column.

```
df.m <- melt(df, id="Years")
df.m$measure <- gsub("(.*) \\(.*", "\\1", df.m$variable)
df.m$facet <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", df.m$variable)
```

Your plotting code, put into a single statement. `colour` and `shape` are now mapped to the measure, not `variable`. The manual `shape` and `colour` scales also only have two entries. I moved the legend to the top just because it was no longer the same size/shape and so didn't line up nicely as it had before; you can put it wherever you want.

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(group=1, x=Years, y=value, colour=measure, shape=measure)) +
    scale_colour_manual(name='', values=c('chartreuse4', 'deepskyblue3')) +
    scale_shape_manual(name='', values=c(19, 17)) +
    geom_point(size=3) +
    facet_grid(.~facet) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=(c(0.0,0.45))) +
    scale_x_discrete("", expand=c(0.01, 0.01)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="") +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title='', ncol=2, keywidth=unit(2,'lines'))) +
    theme(legend.position="top",
          legend.key=element_blank(),
          legend.background=element_rect(colour='black', fill='transparent'),
          legend.text=element_text(size=12),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.margin=unit(1, 'lines'),
          axis.text=element_text(size=12,color="black"),
          axis.title=element_text(size=16),
          strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

---

To answer your exact question about only having certain values show up in the legend, you can use the `breaks` argument to the scale. Use these `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_shape_manual` lines instead:

```
g <- g + scale_colour_manual(name='',
                             breaks=c('% of Women (Physics)', 'Divergence (Physics)'),
                             labels=c('% of Women', 'Divergence'),
                             values=c('chartreuse4', 'deepskyblue3','chartreuse4', 
                                      'deepskyblue3', 'chartreuse4', 'deepskyblue3'))
g <- g + scale_shape_manual(name='',
                            breaks=c('% of Women (Physics)', 'Divergence (Physics)'),
                            labels=c('% of Women', 'Divergence'),
                            values=c(19, 17, 19, 17, 19, 17))
```

However, making your data accurately reflect the things you are trying to map to aesthetics is better in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful explanation of your answer. The code is shorter, simpler, and does what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by simply making a grouping variable for "% of Women" and "Divergence".  Your case is especially easy because those two terms are the exact same length.  You can use `substr` to split out the terms you want from the whole string.  Hopefully someone else will chime in with how to do this within `ggplot2` itself.

Here I just make a new variable representing the two groups you want to color by.

```
df.m$groups = substr(df.m$variable, 1, 10)
```

Then just use this variable as your `color` and `shape` aesthetics instead of `variable`.

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(x=Years, y=value, colour=groups, shape=groups)) +
    geom_point(size=3) + 
    facet_grid(.~facet) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("chartreuse4", "deepskyblue3"))
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. I am going with Brian's answer, however. For a R-novice like me, the explanations really help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to selectively remove from the legend by using a call of scale_* with argument guide='none' or by appending e.g. + guides(color=FALSE)

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/guides.html